probability density function of sin & cos of gaussian random variable
What is the probability density function (pdf) & cumulative distribution function (cdf)
of cos($\theta$) & sin($\theta$), where $\theta$ is a gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$?
The application is to calculate the bit error rate for complex symbols shown below for a gaussian  phase noise on it, to do so I need first to find the pdf of projected real and imaginary amplitude values given by cos($\theta$) and sin($\theta$), respectively.


If $\theta$ is really a Gaussian random variable, it is not living on the the unit circle with undefined limits $-\pi\lt \theta \le \pi $ or $0\lt \theta \le 2 \pi $ ?? , but on $\mathbb R.$

$$\Pr( \cos \theta)  \in dx) = 2 \ \sum_{-\infty}^\infty\mod (\theta , 2 \pi n)\in \text{arccos}(dx), \quad 0 \lt x \le \pi$$
Consider eg a Wiener process $t\to \theta_t = W_t$ on the circle without dicrimination of the number of rounds performed up to time $t.$ The angular  distribution density will be an even function wrt to the start point with a $\delta$ measure and obeys the diffusion equation locally with reflecting boundary condition on the cut of the circle opposite to the start point. It will be an even elliptic Theta function of period $2\pi$ wrt to the start point and one will end with an $\cos^{-1}(\Theta_3(x))$ density, unfortunately too complex to analyze. But there are alternatives by first visit times

Hello Roland, let's make the following assumptions if that would help, the mean value of theta is PI/4 as shown in the figure, and its sigma is much less than PI, so the probability of theta wrapping around is very small that we  can ignore, or we can say $\theta$ is really unwrapped phase. Not sure why you mentioned Wiener process here, $\theta$ here is gaussian not random walk process.

However small the Gaussian, its nowhere zero.. It follows that a Gaussian $N(0,s)$ on the unit circle is not smooth at $\theta=\pm \pi$. The solution of the diffusion equation on the circle is a periodic harmonic function, the density of a Brownian motion on the circle. Of course for small time its a Gaussion, but for $t\to \infty$ its the uniform distributiion.
